# How to setup Minimum orders?

Tags: orders, discount, sales

I would like to sell items with a special price that is activated only if a certain minimum orders threshold is met (E.g. > 50 pieces, 10€ a piece. > 100 pieces, 8€ a piece etc..).

The orders do not need to be for the same buyer, but per website. (before a certain date, to be coupled with  pre-orders). Is it somehow supported? or maybe a good extension?

Comment: http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-price-tier.html

Comment: **Not a duplicate!** "The orders do not need to be for the same buyer, but per website"